# Laravel: Even though I added use Input; I get "Class 'Input' not found"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my AuthorController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Author;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use View;
use Input;

class AuthorController extends Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $author_name = Input::get('name');
    $author_slug = Input::get('slug');
    $author_bio = Input::get('bio');

    $new_author = Author::create(array('name' => $author_name, 'slug' => $author_slug, 'bio' => $author_bio));

    return Redirect::to('/');

  }

}

?>
```

This is what's in my Routes file

```
Route::post('/create-author', [
  'as' => 'create-author',
  'uses' => 'AuthorController@index'
]);
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong, I tried hardcoding something into the database with `$new_author = Author::create(array('name' => 'John));` and it worked, would it be the directory in which the Input class is in relative to my AuthorController.php, which is in `App\Controllers`

Comment: Try this,  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Comment: It worked, thank you! Can you write that in an answer so I can choose it as correct ? Thank you

Comment: Okay thanks i'll accept in approximately 9 minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your controller,

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time when you want to use predefined class , you can see the alias defined for it in **config/app.php**. you should use via facade only,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```